# Position of object in database

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have got model `Team` and I've got (i.e.) `team = Team.first :offset => 20`. Now I need to get number of position of my `team` in db table.

I can do it in  ruby:

```
Team.all.index team #=> 20
```

But I am sure that I can write it on SQL and it will be less expensive for me with big tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the order is made by ID desc:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  def position
    self.class.count(:conditions => ['id <= ?', self.id]) 
  end
end
```

Comment: yep. That's good way!  not very flexible. But for me it is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm following along, but will position value be used a lot it might be worth making sure it is set on save. Will a team change position over time or is it static?

I don't think the position of a record in the database is one of the things a database really cares for, that kind of data should be up to you to set.

Depending on the database you may be able to use the `LIMIT` clause, but you can't use it to find the position of a certain row. Just to select rows number 20 to 21 for example, but it'll differ depending on sorting order.

```
SELECT * FROM teams LIMIT 20,21
```

I think setting a position attribute on your model or having a join model is the way to go.

Comment: position always changes because of deleting and adding data, and I don't want to add position to model. _vlad.zloteanu_ suggested good solution really