# HOWTO rank items by balance in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am implementing a betting system and each user has a balance , how can i find a rank of a user using activerecord methods?
thanks for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763801/position-of-object-in-database

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To get the rank of a user,

```
Users.all(:order => "balance").index(a_particular_user)
```

This should give you the index (rank) of a particular user within the array of all users (sorted by balance).

Answer (score 10):

A slightly more efficient solution if you have a lot of users:

```
Users.order(:balance).pluck(:id).index(a_particular_user_id)`
```

That way, your app fetches n integer ids instead of pulling and instantiating n whole `User` records/objects. Could end up orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: With this method my query took 30 ms, using only ".index" through the user object, took 250ms. Very efficient solution!

Answer (score 5):

few days ago I've asked just the same question

[Position of object in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763801/position-of-object-in-database)

my solution was just the same as @Drew Johnson suggested (`User.all.index current_user`). But I needed "query solution" and @Vlad Zloteanu gave me great idea:

```
User.count(:order => "balance", :conditions => ['balance < (?)', current_user.balance])
```

this is fast query solution for big tables of data.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood what you want, you just need to order the users by balance

```
User.all(:order => "balance")
```

**Edit:** unless `balance` isn't an attribute...

**Edit#2:** after seeing Drew Johnson's answer I realized I misunderstood your question. As he said, you can use the [`index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002178) method to do what you want.

```
@user = User.first
@rank = User.all(:order => "balance").index(@user)
```