# (will_paginate) Find the page a record is in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, will-paginate

My setup: Rails 2.3.10, Ruby 1.8.7

I'm using the will_paginate plugin and for a particular user, I need to implement a leaderboard feature showing the page his rating belongs to, is there a way to do that?

**UPDATE:**
Ideally, this is done without returning all the records first, doing so negates a key benefit of using will_paginate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HOWTO rank items by balance in Ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813495/howto-rank-items-by-balance-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: Thanks, this works great though I forgot to mention a crucial point in my post. As mentioned by Nick, this returns all the records first which defeats the purpose of using pagination in the first place, it will be a huge table, is there anyway to accomplish this using SQL?

Comment: **User.select('count(*)').where("users.rating > ?", User.find(id).rating).order('users.rating DESC')** to only get the count, and limit it to the top of the table. You could also limit it to the bottom, but which one is faster will of course depend on the user's rating and the distribution of the data.

Comment: Oops Rails 2: **User.find(:all, :select => 'count(*)', :order => 'rating DESC', :conditions => [rating > ?', User.find(id).rating])**

Comment: Right idea but the code didn't work, this works User.count(:order => 'rating DESC', :conditions => ['rating > ?', User.find(id).rating]). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Using `.index` does not work with `will-paginate`. For example, I have a `posts` relation. I want to find the index of `post`. `posts.pluck(:id).index(post.id) => 101`. I therefore calculate that this post is on page 11 (page size = 10). Yet when I paginate, it appears on page 18. I'm not sure why but there is clearly some janky behavior here with `will-paginate`.

Answer (score 1):

You know how many users are shown per page, and you can find out what rank the user is so is it not a simple matter of dividing the rank by the users per page and then flooring the result?

Comment: Actually I don't know what the user's rank is, I have to determine that also plus the ratings aren't consecutively numbered either, hope that makes sense

Comment: Then I think you just need to all off the users back ordered by rating (descending) and then find the index of your current user in the results (which is what jimworm has given you a link to). Once you've done that part then it's just a matter of dividing and flooring.

Comment: Yeah, that'll work though getting all the users back negates a key advantage of using will_paginate. This will be a big performance hit when the table gets big and it will. Any other suggestions?